# Showing primary key via PHP and MS Access 2010

Tags: php, ms-access-2010

I’ve been at this for a few hours now. I’m trying to display the primary key of a given table on an access database. First is was trying the `odbc_primarykeys` function and  then tried `odbc_statistics`.

Both give the error:

> odbc_primarykeys(): SQL error: Failed to fetch error message, SQL
>   state HY000 in SQLPrimaryKeys

and

> odbc_statistics(): SQL error: Failed to fetch error message, SQL state
>   HY000 in SQLStatistics.

Here’s my code:

```
$dbu = realpath('E:\AccessBackEnds\Universal\UniversalBackEnd.accdb');
$connu = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=$dbu",'','') or die ("Unable to connect to server");

$result1 = odbc_primarykeys($connu, "UniversalBackEnd", "Administrators", "UserInformation");

$result2 = odbc_statistics($connu, "UniversalBackEnd", "Administrators", "UserInformation", 1, 0);
```

I’ve tried leaving the database name (`UniversalBackEnd`) and the owner (`Administrators`) blank and got the same error. The HY000 error in a Google search didn’t help much and the [php.net](http://www.php.net) pages are surprisingly light on support. Functions like `odbc_field_len` & `odbc_field_type` work fine on the page. Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there is no way to retrieve that information via the Access ODBC driver. You'll probably need to use `com_dotnet` and ACE DAO to get it:

```php
$pkFields = array();
$dbe = new COM("DAO.DBEngine.120");
$db = $dbe->OpenDatabase("C:\\Users\\Public\\foo.accdb");
$tbd = $db->TableDefs("Table2");
foreach ($tbd->Indexes as $idx) {
    if ($idx->Primary) {
        foreach ($idx->Fields as $fld) {
            $pkFields[] = $fld->Name;
        }
        break;
    }
}
$db->Close();
print_r($pkFields);
```

Sample result for a table with two fields (columns) as its Primary Key:

```
Array
(
    [0] => City
    [1] => State
)
```

Comment: After a few months of searching, I finally found a solution that works for MSAccess 2000 .mdb, PDO, PHP. Thank you so much. I can't wait to switch over to MySQL.. Thank you!